# Union results of two functions in php class

Tags: php, class

I have php class(simple example):

```
<?php class test{
    public function __construct() {
        //some code
    }

    public function __destruct() {
        //some code
    }

    public function echo1 {
        //some code
        return 1;
    }

    public function echo2 {
        //some code
        return 2;
    }
}
```

How could I return results of this two functions echo1 and echo2 in class in one row don't creating two new objects for each function?

Comment: *How* do you want the two values returned?

Comment: Why would you have to create two different objects at all?

Answer (score 1):

```
$obj= new Test;
echo $obj->echo1().$obj->echo2();
```

Also, capitalize class names, and you'll need parentheses on those functions:

```
class Test{
    public function __construct() {
        //some code
    }

    public function __destruct() {
        //some code
    }

    public function echo1() {
        //some code
        return "Hello";
    }

    public function echo2() {
        //some code
        return "World";
    }
}
$obj= new Test;
echo $obj->echo1()." ".$obj->echo2();
```

Answer (score 1):

You may have to change your functions a little bit.

```
...

public function echo1() {
    //some code
    echo 1;
    return $this;
}

public function echo2() {
    //some code
    echo 2;
    return $this;
}

...
```

Then call it like this.

```
(new test())->echo1()->echo2();
```